# Google App Engine sends too much data with JSON

Tags: android, json, google-app-engine

I created a very simple API with GAE and Cloud Endpoints, using the Datastore. I have made an Entity named Book with some attributes (most of them are Strings) and deployed the application.

My GET and POST requests work correctly, however I don't understand why each time I do a GET request to retrieve my entities in the datastore there is an extra line in the JSON, for instance:

```
{
        "id": "5634482569460976",
        "date": "20141125",
        "author": "Charly",
        "kind": "bookendpoint#resourcesItem"
    }
```

I never set a "kind" attribute in my Entity, where does that come from?
Besides at the end of each json response I can find these two lines:

```
"kind": "bookendpoint#resources",
"etag": "\"dIDB-NLukmBT86-tBYjgZpbt2_Y/FcVIa289PJU7Cjr-bG8b0oxmfrKQ\""
```

I don't know where those "kind" and "etag" come from either.

Can you tell me what are these and how to prevent them from appearing in the JSON responses?

Comment: Did you find how to remove these tags?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both attributes are added automatically by Cloud Endpoints. I do not know how to remove it and Google does not seem to document why they are added, but some of it is easy to guess.

**The `kind` field**

`kind` indicates to the Android client how to serialize (transform from JSON text to Java object) the data. This is useful when polymorphism comes into play. For example imagine that you will return this class from the endpoint :

```
public class Library {
  public List<Item> items;
}

public interface Item{
  private String title;
}

public class Book extends Item {
}

public class Magazine extends Item {
}
```

Then assume that your Android client receives this JSON data :

```
{
  "items": [
           {"title":"My book"},
           {"title":"My magazine"},
      ]
}
```

Then how does the client know which item is a `Book` and which is a `Magazine` ? Those classes could have completely different behavior on the client side so it's important to know.

But if you add the `kind` field, the serializer will be able to pick up the right `Item` implementation :

```
{
  "kind": "bookendpoint#Library"
  "items": [
           {"title":"My book","kind": "bookendpoint#Book"},
           {"title":"My magazine","kind": "bookendpoint#Magazine"},
      ]
}
```

**The `etag` field**

This one is a bit more mysterious to me. In the HTTP protocol, ETags are some kind of hashes for a resource, that are used to cache the resource on client side and avoid downloading it again if it has not changed.

Typically the server will provide an ETag when it serves the resource, and then the client will ask "Give me that resource, unless the ETag XXX is still valid". There's still an HTTP request involved but no download is required unless the resource has changed on the server side.

You can read more on ETags on [this Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_ETag).

ETags would be of great use with Cloud Endpoints. I am guessing that Cloud Endpoints computes some hash of the response it wants to return. If this response matches the `etag` field provided by the Cloud Endpoints client, no data is returned and instead an `HTTP 304 Not Modified` response is sent.