# Handling Extra JSON Tags sent from Google App Engine API

Tags: json, google-app-engine

I am trying to figure out the best way to handle extra JSON returned on a 200 Success from Google App Engine.

Here is a sample of the JSON being returned from GAE

```
{
 "username": "yo",
 "password": "yo",
 "email": "yo",
 "id": "5654313976201216",
 "kind": "photoswap#userItem",
 "etag": "\"XUjxKcsckN9zXROpZ4Yj2GJxcXg/L6Zg-XPyGcr_RGBFQBwHhIYcdBQ\""
}
```

This does not work with the User Model that I have developed, and was causing issues because of the gson json mapping. The fields "kind" and "etag" are not part of the response message that I created, and was wondering if there is a way to remove that from being sent back from the server.

The api I have developed is written in Python

As of right now I just included those 2 values in my User Object Model, but I would like to not have to.

Comment: If you're using Google Endpoints, as I believe you probably are, **please** tag your question appropriately -- this JSON is returned from *Google Endpoints*, after all!, only tangentially from App Engine.  Also showing the gist of your code causing this to be returned would help us help you!

Comment: ...and if this is indeed about Endpoints, then it's a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27201779/google-app-engine-sends-too-much-data-with-json .